# Difference between basicHttp binding in webservices and WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services, basichttpbinding, wse2.0

What is the difference between WCF and WSE2.0 webservices when it comes to implementation of basic httpbinding. Can anyone point out what may be the subtle differnces when it come sto use the same protocol but using different technology.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but I've only run into a difference once.  I generated wcf proxies against a very old asmx webservice and ran into serialization errors on certain operations.  When I regenerated the code using a "legacy" web reference everything worked fine.

Comment: I vaguely remember there being several service packs for that version of WSE. I think there were difference in the way the code behaved depending on which SP was installed. Don't remember what behavior was different though. Using a web reference (ASMX) instead of a service reference (WCF) in Visual Studio is good advice if you do run into issues with WCF since ASMX technology was designed to replace WSE.

Comment: "ASMX technology was designed to replace WSE"? I think you mean that WCF was designed to replace WSE.

Answer (score 0):

A very good article [describing this is here](http://jai-on-asp.blogspot.com/2010/04/difference-between-web-services-and-wcf.html).

Also the various [wcf bindings are explained here](http://jai-on-asp.blogspot.com/2011/11/comparison-of-various-bindings-in-wcf.html)

hope this helps.